# Не получается создать прокет ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

Хочу создать проект ASP.NET. Открываю Visual Studio 2022 Community И выбираю ASP.NET Core Empty. Решение создается без ошибок но.. проекта нет, просто написано Solution "app" (0 projects)
Такая же проблема при попытке создания проекта Blazor Web App
Никаких ошибок нет, может кто сталкивался что делать?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: **Empty** - пустое решение, проектов в нём нет. Создавайте взамен проект конкретного типа.

Comment: Тогда почему при создании Blazor Web App тоже самое?

Answer (score 0):

как подметил абсолютно верно в комментарии **Alexander Petrov:** *Empty - пустое решение*

Поэтому создавайте проект aspNet не empty ( *И выбираю ASP.NET Core Empty.* => я не нашла в каком проекте можно так выбрать )

При создании же к примеру `wasm` по умолчанию создает проект со страницами `7` версия и ниже, если вы отметили или нет галкой `AspNet` одинаково решение со страницами

а что касается 8 версии, `BlazorWebApp`
там при создания проекта, отметьте галочкой "добавить страницы" (по умолчанию она не отмечена)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]